# Using ajax to populate a html container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my first time experimenting with Ajax.
I have a container called `'.onboarding_steps'` also on my page is a next button with ID `#next`.

I am trying to populate my container with a series of "steps" (html content), when the user clicks Next, the next step is loaded into the container.

I'd like to do this using Ajax.
My code at the minute looks like this:

```
var steps = [
  'This is step one',
  'This is step two',
  'This is step three',
  'This is step four'
],
counter = 0;
$('.onboarding_steps').html(steps[counter]); // your initial value
$('#next').click(function () {
  counter = (counter + 1) % steps.length; // increment your counter
  $('.onboarding_steps').html(steps[counter]); // the new incremented value
});
```

This code currently iterates through each step. However, now I would like to take this further and use Ajax. How can I acheieve something like this:

```
var steps = [
  $.get( "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step1.php", function( data ) {
      $( ".onboarding_steps" ).html( data );
  }),
  $.get( "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step2.php", function( data ) {
      $( ".onboarding_steps" ).html( data );
  }),
  $.get( "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step3.php", function( data ) {
      $( ".onboarding_steps" ).html( data );
  }),
  $.get( "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step4.php", function( data ) {
      $( ".onboarding_steps" ).html( data );
  })
],
counter = 0;
$('.onboarding_steps').html(steps[counter]); // your initial value
$('#next').click(function () {
  counter = (counter + 1) % steps.length; // increment your counter
  $('.onboarding_steps').html(steps[counter]); // the new incremented value
});
```

Currently this code just displays the last step, instead of allowing me to run through each step one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the array with the urls like this:

```
var steps = [
  "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step1.php",
  "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step2.php",
  "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step3.php",
  "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step4.php"
]
```

Then load them everytime they make click (and at the beginning):

```
counter = 0;
loadURL(steps[counter]);
$('#next').click(function () {
  counter = (counter + 1) % steps.length; // increment your counter
  loadURL(steps[counter]); // the new incremented value
});

function loadURL(url){
    $.get(url, function( data ) {
       $( ".onboarding_steps" ).html( data );
    });
}
```

There's actually a better way to load the response of the request into a container with `$.load`:

```
$('.onboarding_steps').load(url);
```

That way you'd write:

```
counter = 0;
$('.onboarding_steps').load(steps[counter]);
$('#next').click(function () {
  counter = (counter + 1) % steps.length; // increment your counter
  $('.onboarding_steps').load(steps[counter]); // the new incremented value
});
```

And no need for any other function.

**Edit** : An Array might not be needed if you can just use the counter to produce the url:

```
var baseUrl = "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step";
var steps = 4; /*or however many steps it got*/
```

And then you just simply load the url like this:

```
$('.onboarding_steps').load(baseUrl + (counter + 1) + '.php');
```

Counter increments now are:

```
counter = (counter + 1) % steps;
```

Comment: This loads the first file, but then on click returns the error loadUrlURL is not defined

Comment: @SamSkirrow, I just realized the typo. Should have been `loadURL`.

Comment: Amazing, that works like a treat. Quick question, do all the files have to load before this works?

Comment: No, they are loaded on a click basis.

Comment: The purpose of the array is to hold individual urls, but it isn't actually needed if all that changes in the url is the last number (just concatenate the counter). But if all urls are very different, the array works.

Comment: I see, it is the case that all tat changes in the url is the number - how would I make your code reflect this?

Comment: The edits return the following error: steps is not defined

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is asyncronous, you would need to make the second call in the callback to the first, and the third in the callback for the second, and the 4th in the callback for the 3rd...right now they are all executing more or less at the same time - i.e. not waiting for the previous one to finish.

Comment: I think I understand, but could you perhaps provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

As the $.get will return a promise (and not the result itself), `counter[0]`  is not actually the response value, is the call to the method. When you are going `steps[counter]` you are actually making the call, so that's why the last step is being shown (basically is the last in process, so it's executing the `$().html(data)` method.

What you can do is initialize the data, and then access it:

```
 steps = [];
 $.get( "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step1.php", function( data ) {
      steps[0] = data;
  }),
  $.get( "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step2.php", function( data ) {
      steps[1] = data;
  }),
  $.get( "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step3.php", function( data ) {
      steps[2] = data;
  }),
  $.get( "wp-content/plugins/skizzar-onboarding/ajax/step4.php", function( data ) {
      steps[3] = data;
  })
```

(you will have to wait until these calls are made to start the use of `steps`)